# Angular and firebase : Not able to access code property of error object in catch block

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Trying to capture error code from firebase in catch block. But Error Interface doesn't have code property to access. Giving compile time error.

```
Userlogin(email, password) {
this.af.auth.login({
  email: email,
  password: password
},
  {
    provider: AuthProviders.Password,
    method: AuthMethods.Password
  }
).catch(err=>{console.log(err.code)}); //err.code is complaining.
}
```

Any help? Thanks.